# In what movie and for what reason did Superman's throat "inflate"?

Tags: story-identification, dc, movie, superman

What I remember is that in a movie (probably one with Reeve) Superman has trouble in a certain scene and, *as far as I can remember*, his throat inflates becoming big and a bit colored.

I might be terribly wrong but this is what I can remember. Also, I think the throat was glowing somehow, but this might be a fake particular I'm misinterpreting from my memories.

I've tried searching both pictures and videos on YouTube, but didn't manage to find anything.

What movie is this from and why did it happen? Also, is this featured in the Comics too, or is it just in the movie?

Comment: [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkSaAhbceBk) comes to mind.

Comment: I can't recall any real throat-expanding scenes (or glowing ones, though this aspect makes me think Superman IV and Nuclear Man), however the somewhat memorable scene in Superman III where [Clark vs. Superman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XY3dxb5OpIw) has a lot of throat/choking action and at a couple points his veins are really popping. The scene concludes with Clark choking and destroying his evil Superman side, which MAY be where the focus on the throat came from in memory?

Comment: I watched that yesterday but it doesn't look like so. I'll keep on looking, but as I underlined in the question, I just might be terribly wrong (I hope not). :D

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be what you have in mind. It's from Superman 3 and is described as the "Fight scene".

Evil Superman and Clark are fighting. Clark chokes Superman to death. You can clearly see that his throat is swollen although not glowing.

[image: Clark fights Superman]